# Count duplicates as one

Tags: excel, duplicates

Hi I need help on how can is make a formula in Excel.

I have 3 systems System S101, S102, S103. The latest revision of system S101 is rev. 02 and its Accepted. System S102 and S103 are all Rejected. System S101 Rev. 00 and Rev. 01 should not be included in the counting for Rejected because Rev. 02 was already Accepted. so I need an output like this REJECTED = 2 and Accepted = 1.

System-Revision-Status

S101-00-REJECTED

S101-01-REJECTED

S101-02-ACCEPTED

S102-00-REJECTED

S103-00-REJECTED

OUTPUT: ACCEPTED = 2 REJECTED = 1

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed overview of how your data is ordered in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your Excel file looks like this:

[image: Excel file]

In the Cells B11 and C11 I use the following functions to calculate the maximum value in the revision column for the specified System No. given in A11.

```
B11=MAX(IF(A2:A6=A11;IF(C2:C6=B10;B2:B6)))
C11=MAX(IF(A2:A6=A11;IF(C2:C6=C10;B2:B6)))
```

Make sure to enter the functions with `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` as they are array functions.

The IF functions within the MAX function make sure you will only return the rows from Column B where the columns A and C match the criteria (System No. and Accepted/Rejected).

**EDIT:** As the true question seems to be unclear; if the `Count` is needed; than simply replace the `MAX` for `COUNT`

**EDIT 2**  Fixed == typo

Comment: should count only 1 for System 101 since the latest revision was Accepted already and the other system are count as Rejected.

Comment: @pnuts, within the text of the question it says clearly `the latest revision` I think that the output is just a typo after editing the post back and forth.

Comment: @pnuts True to that! but is that reason enough to down vote an answer?